# Boolean in PowerShell while loop

Tags: powershell, while-loop, boolean

How to control the while loop using boolean in Powershell?

```
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, HelpMessage = "Name. -1 for all names.")] 
    [string]$name
)

try
{
    $selected = $false
    while($selected -eq $false)
    {
        if($name -eq "-1")
        {
            write-host "Displaying all names"
            Get-Name | select name
        }
        else
        {
            # do some code here
            $selected = $true
        }
    }
}
catch
{
    'Name {0} was not found. Provide a valid name.' -f $name
    exit(0)
}
```

Expected behavior:

1. User is prompted to enter name
2. If the user doesn't know the name, they can type -1
3. When -1 typed, the user is presented with all names
4. Code doesn't quit while loop

Comment: What is `Get-Name`?

Comment: I'm presuming that the `get-name | select-name` is just pseudo code that has been omitted. Feed, when I run your code I made two modifications: commented out the 'get-name|select-name' and added 'pause` underneath it. When I do this, I get `Displaying All Names` followed by `hit enter to continue` (this is from the pause I added). This repeats ad-nausea until I manually stop the code. So in your current code, you appear to have already achieved your stated goal. Can you better explain what your code does not currently allow you to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `$selected` to `$true` to exit the loop when user enter `"-1"` in `$name`.

I don't really understand why you loop ?